# How do you manage dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js file with version control in magento2?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, git, grunt

The themes.js file contains important configuration and without it you cannot run grunt tasks for your theme:

```
#dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js 
mytheme: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Package/mytheme',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
```

This is why we track that file with git.

The issue is that every time I update magento2 to a new version, like from 2.0.5 to 2.0.6, that file gets reset to its default contents, so my theme configuration is lost. I have to go back in the repo and recommit that file.

Any solution? Do you track that file?

Thanks!

Comment: i've opened an [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4697) with a pull request to solve this, but they are still thinking about it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 add new theme without changing core files. Grunt](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121349/magento-2-add-new-theme-without-changing-core-files-grunt)

Comment: @Meogi the answers there are very poor solutions to the problem. Magento will provide a solution for this one in 2.2 with  themes.loc.js config files.

Comment: Thanks @ClaudiuCreanga this is good news to know! I was unaware of their plans regarding area of development.