# Magento 2 - Registering a new Grunt task without editing Gruntfile.js

Tags: magento2, grunt

Following on from this question: [Magento 2 add new theme without changing core files. Grunt](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121349/magento-2-add-new-theme-without-changing-core-files-grunt)

The goal is to register a new Grunt task called "development". To do this, `grunt.registerTask` is needed, however I can't get access to "grunt" in my `Gruntfile.theme.js` to then use `grunt.registerTask`

My files are setup exactly as they are in https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121350/28664 answer.

If any more information is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an additional task in a seperate folder to that of Magento's dev/tools/grunt/tasks by simply using the `--tasks` flag that is available on the grunt cli.

Create a file in a location of your choice, I created my file here:

```
./dev/tools/grunt/custom/tasks/hello.js
```

The contents of this were as follows:

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  'use strict';

  var fs      = require('fs'),
      log     = grunt.log.write,
      ok      = grunt.log.ok,
      error   = grunt.log.error;

  grunt.registerTask('hello', function () {
    log('hello!');
  });

};
```

To use this tasks, I had to run my grunt command using the `--tasks` flag, which looks like:

```
grunt --tasks=./dev/tools/grunt/custom/tasks hello
```

This runs my "hello" task.

What I wanted to was actually create a new task that would run some of the other tasks that I've defined, so I created another file along side `hello.js` called `development.js`. This task will call `hello`

The contents of `development.js` looks like:

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  'use strict';

  var fs = require('fs'),
      _  = require('underscore');

  grunt.registerTask('development', function () {
    var tasks = [
      'hello'
    ];
    grunt.task.run(tasks);
  });

};
```

As you can see, you can populate the "tasks" array with various other tasks you would like to run, such as `cssmin` etc.

This coupled with the extending the Grunt file as per this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121350/28664 means that we can really extend the core Grunt configuration of Magento 2 without touching any core files at all.